# gmock multiple sequences with duplicate EXPACT_CALL with same arguments

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

I have a problem to properly setup a test for a turtle-graphic interface.

As sample I have a simplified interface for just drawing a line.

Now I want to write a test for drawing some grid `draw_grid` and ensure that each line of the grid is drawn, but the actual order of drawn lines does not matter. I only need to ensure, that the method calls to `move_to` and `line_to` are properly paired. I tried this with `InSequence` but this leads to several issues, because a couple of `line_to` and `move_to` calls are used for two lines.

For example `move_to(0,0)` is used for the top edge of the grid and for the left border of the first cell. So the test will generate two `EXPACT_CALL(sot, move_to(0,0))` in two different sequences, but each of them implicitly with `Times(1)`. So I guess this is the main problem. This will happen for each left and top border of a row and similarly for `line_to` for right and bottom border of a row.

I also tried to use `After` for an `EXPACT_CALL`, but this just leads to different test errors.

Is there any nice way to specify the requested behavior? Thanks for your help!

```cpp
using testing::InSequence;

struct ITurtle
{
    virtual void move_to(int x, int y) = 0;
    virtual void line_to(int x, int y) = 0;
    void line(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) { move_to(x0, y0); line_to(x1, y1); }
};

class TurtleMock
    : public ITurtle
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD(void, move_to, (int x, int y), (override));
    MOCK_METHOD(void, line_to, (int x, int y), (override));
};

void draw_grid(ITurtle &t)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < 100; r += 10)
    {
        // top
        t.line(0,r,100,r);
        for (int c = 0; c < 100; c += 10)
        { // left
            t.line(c,r,c,r+10);
        }
        // right
        t.line(100,r,100,r+10);
    }
    // bottom
    t.line(0,100,100,100);
}

TEST(TurtleTest, lines)
{
    TurtleMock sot;
    for (int r = 0; r < 100; r += 10)
    {
        {
            InSequence s;
            EXPECT_CALL(sot, move_to(0, r));
            EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_to(100, r));
        }
        for (int c = 0; c < 100; c += 10)
        {
            InSequence s;
            EXPECT_CALL(sot, move_to(c,r));
            EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_to(c,r+10));
        }
        {
            InSequence s;
            EXPECT_CALL(sot, move_to(100, r));
            EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_to(100, r + 10));
        }
    }
    {
        InSequence s;
        EXPECT_CALL(sot, move_to(0, 100));
        EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_to(100, 100));
    }

    draw_grid(sot);
}
```

**EDIT**:
Extension to proposed solution of Sedenion to support polygon drawing with one initial `move_to` followed by a sequence of `line_to` statements.

```
void move_to(int x, int y) final
{
    m_move_to_data = {x, y};
}

void line_to(int x, int y) final
{
    ASSERT_TRUE(m_move_to_data.has_value());
    auto const [x0, y0] = *m_move_to_data;
    line_mock(x0, y0, x, y);
    m_move_to_data = {x, y};
}
```

Comment: Please read the tag [tag:gmock] description carefully: Gmock is a mocking framework for **Groovy**, but your question is C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following simplified example of drawing just 2 lines ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/qf13nzbTj)):

```
void draw_two_lines(ITurtle &t)
{
    t.line(0, 0, 10, 0);
    t.line(0, 0, 0, 10);
}


TEST(TurtleTest, two_lines)
{
    TurtleMock sot;
    
    {
        InSequence s;
        EXPECT_CALL(sot, move_to(0, 0)); // (2)
        EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_to(10, 0));
    }
    {
        InSequence s;
        EXPECT_CALL(sot, move_to(0, 0)); // (1)
        EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_to(0, 10));
    }   

    draw_two_lines(sot);
}
```

Forgetting about `InSequence` for a moment, expectations are matched in reverse order (from bottom to top) by default by Google Mock.
Quote from the [manual](http://google.github.io/googletest/gmock_for_dummies.html):

> By default, when a mock method is invoked, gMock will search the expectations in the reverse order they are defined, and stop when an active expectation that matches the arguments is found (you can think of it as “newer rules override older ones.”).

Now, here we do have `InSequence`, i.e. two groups. However, the two groups themselves are not "in sequence". That means gMock will match the first call to `move_to(0, 0)` with the **second** group (marked by `(1)` in the code above). Thus, afterwards, `line_to(0, 10)` is expected but `line_to(10, 0)` gets called, resulting in a test failure. If you exchange the order of the two InSequence-groups, the test will pass. However, this is not really worth anything since your goal is to have the order independent.

What you want is basically to specify something like one "atomic" match of all 4 parameters.
I am not aware of any way to directly express this with the `InSequence` or `After` machinery of GoogleMock. Thus, I propose to take another approach and store the call of `move_to` in a temporary variable, and in the call of `line_to` take the remembered two values and the two given values to call a dedicated mock function ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/q7o79TfK7)):

```
struct ITurtle
{
    virtual void move_to(int x, int y) = 0;
    virtual void line_to(int x, int y) = 0;
    void line(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1) { move_to(x0, y0); line_to(x1, y1); }
};

class TurtleMock : public ITurtle
{
public:
    std::optional<std::pair<int, int>> move_to_data;

    virtual void move_to(int x, int y) final {
        ASSERT_FALSE(move_to_data.has_value());
        move_to_data = {x, y};
    }

    virtual void line_to(int x1, int y1) final {
        ASSERT_TRUE(move_to_data.has_value());
        auto const [x0, y0] = *move_to_data;
        line_mock(x0, y0, x1, y1);
        move_to_data.reset();
    }

    MOCK_METHOD(void, line_mock, (int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1));
};

void draw_two_lines(ITurtle &t)
{
    t.line(0, 0, 10, 0);
    t.line(0, 0, 0, 10);
}

TEST(TurtleTest, two_lines)
{
    TurtleMock sot;

    EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_mock(0, 0, 10, 0));
    EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_mock(0, 0, 0, 10));

    draw_two_lines(sot);
}
```

This allows to specify all 4 parameters in one "atomic" match, making the whole stuff with `InSequence` unnecessary. The above example passes regardless of the order of the `line()` calls in `draw_two_lines()`.

Your test for `draw_grid()` would then become ([live example](https://godbolt.org/z/q7o79TfK7)):

```
TEST(TurtleTest, grid)
{
    TurtleMock sot;
    for (int r = 0; r < 100; r += 10)
    {
        EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_mock(0, r, 100, r));
        for (int c = 0; c < 100; c += 10) {
            EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_mock(c, r, c, r+10));
        }
        EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_mock(100, r, 100, r + 10));
    }
    EXPECT_CALL(sot, line_mock(0, 100, 100, 100));

    draw_grid(sot);
}
```

Note: This solution assumes that you cannot or do not want to make `ITurtle::line()` virtual. If it were, you could of course ditch the helper `move_to_data` and `line_mock()` and instead mock `line()` directly.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response (upvote). Is it right, that this approach needs always `move_to` - `line_to` pairs? I know I didn't put in question in that detail, but for turtle graphics, it is also allowed to have just one initial `move_to` followed by a sequence of `line_to`s, e.g. to draw a polygon. And it would be good if the mock can reflect this behavior.

Comment: Yes, the mock I have shown always requires pairs of `move_to` and `line_to`. For other cases, I suggest to use a second different mock class (which is your original mock class), where you set expectations for the two functions separately. So you have one `MockForGrid` and one `NormalMock`, or something like that.